# using filter and generator to generator endless prime number in python

Tags: python, algorithm, generator, yield

Below is a python program I found to find prime numbers using [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes). It uses filter and generator. I'm not able to understand it.

```
def _odd_iter():
    n = 1
    while True:
        n = n + 2
        yield n

def _not_divisible(n):
    return lambda x: x % n > 0

def primes():
    yield 2
    it = _odd_iter()
    while True:
        n = next(it)
        yield n
        it = filter(_not_divisible(n), it)

for n in primes():
    if n < 1000:
        print(n)
    else:
        break
```

What I don't understand is `it = filter(_not_divisible(n), it)`. For example for number 105, how is it excluded by this single line of code?

Comment: are you familiar with decorators? It will be much simpler to explain using this concept

Comment: I do know how decorator works, could you please explain it in detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each prime number found a `filter` is applied to the iterable, the filter used is a function that excludes all multiples of the prime number.

So your iterable is wrapped in as many filters as you found prime numbers, for example the number 105 is excluded because it's divisible by 3 and the filter for all multiples of 3 was added when you found the prime number 3.

If you add some `print` statements it will be a bit clearer (I hope):

```
def _odd_iter():
    n = 1
    while True:
        n = n + 2
        yield n

def _not_divisible(n):
    print('add filter for all multiples of', n)
    return lambda x: print('check if', x, 'is divisible by', n, 'result: ', not (x % n > 0)) or x % n > 0

def primes():
    yield 2
    it = _odd_iter()
    while True:
        n = next(it)
        yield n
        it = filter(_not_divisible(n), it)

for n in primes():
    if n < 20:
        print(n)
    else:
        break
```

which prints:

```
2
3
add filter for all multiples of 3
check if 5 is divisible by 3 result:  False
5
add filter for all multiples of 5
check if 7 is divisible by 3 result:  False
check if 7 is divisible by 5 result:  False
7
add filter for all multiples of 7
check if 9 is divisible by 3 result:  True
check if 11 is divisible by 3 result:  False
check if 11 is divisible by 5 result:  False
check if 11 is divisible by 7 result:  False
11
add filter for all multiples of 11
check if 13 is divisible by 3 result:  False
check if 13 is divisible by 5 result:  False
check if 13 is divisible by 7 result:  False
check if 13 is divisible by 11 result:  False
13
add filter for all multiples of 13
check if 15 is divisible by 3 result:  True
check if 17 is divisible by 3 result:  False
check if 17 is divisible by 5 result:  False
check if 17 is divisible by 7 result:  False
check if 17 is divisible by 11 result:  False
check if 17 is divisible by 13 result:  False
17
add filter for all multiples of 17
check if 19 is divisible by 3 result:  False
check if 19 is divisible by 5 result:  False
check if 19 is divisible by 7 result:  False
check if 19 is divisible by 11 result:  False
check if 19 is divisible by 13 result:  False
check if 19 is divisible by 17 result:  False
19
add filter for all multiples of 19
check if 21 is divisible by 3 result:  True
check if 23 is divisible by 3 result:  False
check if 23 is divisible by 5 result:  False
check if 23 is divisible by 7 result:  False
check if 23 is divisible by 11 result:  False
check if 23 is divisible by 13 result:  False
check if 23 is divisible by 17 result:  False
check if 23 is divisible by 19 result:  False
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not just that *single* line of code, it's that line being run repeatedly, with different values of `n`.

Basically, `it` is an iterator that yields candidate prime numbers which have not yet been ruled out by the sieve. You start by making all odd numbers candidates.

```
it = _odd_iter()
```

Then you repeatedly take the first remaining candidate,

```
while True:
    n = next(it)
```

remove all numbers that are multiples of that candidate,

```
    filter(_not_divisible(n), it)
```

and replace your candidate primes with everything that is left after removing multiples.

```
    it = ...
```

If you pretend `filter` returns a list of numbers, rather than an iterable, and also pretend `_odd_iter()` returns a list of odd numbers instead of an iterable, you can trace through the loop and determine what's in the list at each point. For example, after running

```
it = _odd_iter()
```

you start with

```
it = 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, ...
```

Then run

```
    n = next(it) # 3
```

which pulls the first item off the front, leaving you with

```
it = 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, ...
```

and run

```
    it = filter(_not_divisible(3), it)
```

filter out all the multiples of 3,

```
it = 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, ...
```

Then go back to the top of the loop and pull the new first number off the front

```
    n = next(it) # 5
```

leaving

```
it = 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 25, ...
```

and then filter out all the multiples of 5,

```
    it = filter(_not_divisible(5), it)
```

which gives

```
it = 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, ...
```

and so on.

In practice, because `filter()` returns an iterator, not a list, you wind up getting a nested sequence of iterators. In particular, you start with

```
it = _odd_iter()
```

then after the first iteration of the loop, you have basically

```
it = filter(_non_divisible(3), _odd_iter())
```

except that `3` has been taken from the iterator, and then after the second iteration of the loop you have

```
it = filter(_non_divisible(5), filter(_non_divisible(3), _odd_iter()))
```

except that `5` has also been taken from the iterator, and then

```
it = filter(_non_divisible(7), filter(_non_divisible(5), filter(_non_divisible(3), _odd_iter())))
```

and so on.

Comment: Very helpful answer. But I still get question when handling  number, 25. Could you please answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54386716/python-how-does-the-generator-and-filter-work-in-the-codes-generating-prime-lis ?

Answer (score 1):

First, filter over iterator returns another iterator. I.e. when we do something like:

```
it = filter(_not_divisible(3), it)
it = filter(_not_divisible(5), it)
```

We get a chained iterator "odd number AND not divisible by 3 AND not divisible by 5". It is somewhat similar to chained decorators, where we get an equivalent of:

```
# assuming we have decorator @not divisible
@not_divisible(2)
def iter():
    return xrange(inf)

# then, at every subsequent prime we do something like:
iter = not_divisible(3)(iter)
# next prime is 5:
iter = not_divisible(5)(iter)
```

... and so on