# Prime numbers sum - for loop and big numbers

Tags: python, for-loop, optimization, primes

I'm running the following code to find the sum of the first 10,000,000 prime numbers.
How can I optimize it such that it doesn't take forever to obtain the result(the sum of prime numbers)?

```
sum=0
num=2
iterator=0

while iterator<10000000:
    prime = True

    for i in range(2,num):
        if (num%i==0):
            prime = False

    if prime:
        sum=sum+num
         # print (num, sum, iterator)
        iterator=iterator+1
    num=num+1

print(sum)
```

Comment: use a prime sieve probably

Comment: It's bad practice to name a variable that overrides a builtin function (e.g. `sum`). Furthermore `iterator` has a very specific meaning in Python, so I'd avoid that as a variable name too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [using filter and generator to generator endless prime number in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668867/using-filter-and-generator-to-generator-endless-prime-number-in-python)

Comment: No need to change anything, it already won't run forever.

Answer (score 3):

the 10,000,000 th prime is approximately  `n * ln(n) + n * ln( ln(n) )` or  `~188980383` ... then you can use a sieve to find all primes under that value (discard any extras ... (ie you will get about 50k extra prime numbers when using 10million, note this took approximately 8 seconds for me))

see also : [Finding first n primes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4911777/finding-first-n-primes)

see also : [Fastest way to list all primes below N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068372/fastest-way-to-list-all-primes-below-n)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).  It's a much faster method to find the first *n* prime numbers.

Comment: isnt that to find all primes under N ... which is significantly different than the nth prime (but you are right in essense)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Yes, that is what the question is asking and what I specified in my answer. This finds the first n primes, which you can use to calculate the sum.

Comment: no... its asking for the sum of the first 10Million primes... not the sum of all primes under 10million (there are about 650k primes that are less than 10Million)

Comment: @JoranBeasley Oh, I see. Okay, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) is fairly simple to implement in Python by using correct slicing. So you can use it to recover the *n* first primes and sum them.

It was pointed out in Joran Beasley's answer that an upper bound for the *n*-th prime is `n * ln(n) + n * ln( ln(n) )`, which we can use and then discrard the extra primes. Note that this bound does not work for *n* smaller than 6.

```
from math import log

def sum_n_primes(n):
    # Calculate the upper bound
    upper = int(n * ( log(n) + log(log(n))))

    # Prepare our Sieve, for readability we make index match the number by adding 0 and 1
    primes = [False] * 2 + [True] * (upper - 1)

    # Remove non-primes
    for x in range(2, int(upper**(1/2) + 1)):
        if primes[x]:
            primes[2*x::x] = [False] * (upper // x - 1) # Replace // by / in Python2

    # Sum the n first primes
    return sum([x for x, is_prime in enumerate(primes) if is_prime][:n])
```

It takes a few seconds, but outputs that the sum of the 10,000,000 first primes is `870530414842019`.

If you need *n* to be any higher, one solution would be to [improve your upper bound](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270814/bounds-for-n-th-prime).