# Python: how does the generator and filter work in the codes generating prime list with filter()

Tags: python, generator, primes, iterable-unpacking

Note:
This question is different with [using filter and generator to generator endless prime number in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668867/using-filter-and-generator-to-generator-endless-prime-number-in-python) although both of them are related to Python code finding all the prime numbers up to a given limit.

The core codes are actually very simple, but it's hard for me to understand how it works. That's the reason I add some debug prints.

```
def _odd_number_generator():
    x = 1
    while True:
        x += 2
        print('    _odd_number_generator, x=', x)
        yield x

def _not_divisible(n):
    def func(x):
        print("      filter calling on x:", x, ", n:", n)
        return x % n > 0
    return func


def _primes():
    yield 2                                 # return first prime: 2
    odd_numbers = _odd_number_generator()   
    print("  in _primes, #a:  odd_numbers=", odd_numbers)
    while True:
        print("  in _primes, #b:         before next(filter) odd_numbers=", odd_numbers)

        # I know this line calling _odd_number_generator and _not_divisible, 
        # but how it works
        n = next(odd_numbers)   

        print("  in _primes, #c:         begin yield n:", n)
        yield n
        print("  in _primes, #d: n=", n, ", after yield  odd_numbers=", odd_numbers)
        odd_numbers = filter(_not_divisible(n), odd_numbers)    
        print("  in _primes, #e: n=", n, ", after filter odd_numbers=", odd_numbers)


def print_prime_numbes():
    for n in _primes():                                          
        print("  in print_prime_numbes, n = ", n)
        if n < 30:
            print(n)
            print()
            print("print_prime_numbes, begin next loop: n=", n)
        else:
            break

def test_print_prime_numbes():
    print("test_output_triangles() >>>")
    print_prime_numbes()
```

The answer in [using filter and generator to generator endless prime number in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41668867/using-filter-and-generator-to-generator-endless-prime-number-in-python) is very helpful to understand the chained iterator. But still, I get problem to understand how the _odd_number_generator and 
_not_divisible is being called when handling the number 25.

For example, here is a piece of outputs when running:

```
print_prime_numbes, begin next loop: n= 23
  in _primes, #d: n= 23 , after yield  odd_numbers= <filter object at 0x000002B0E02366D8>
  in _primes, #e: n= 23 , after filter odd_numbers= <filter object at 0x000002B0E0236F98>
  in _primes, #b:         before next(filter) odd_numbers= <filter object at 0x000002B0E0236F98>
    _odd_number_generator, x= 25
      filter calling on x: 25 , n: 3
      filter calling on x: 25 , n: 5
    _odd_number_generator, x= 27
      filter calling on x: 27 , n: 3
    _odd_number_generator, x= 29
      filter calling on x: 29 , n: 3
      filter calling on x: 29 , n: 5
      filter calling on x: 29 , n: 7
      filter calling on x: 29 , n: 11
      filter calling on x: 29 , n: 13
      filter calling on x: 29 , n: 17
      filter calling on x: 29 , n: 19
      filter calling on x: 29 , n: 23
  in _primes, #c:         begin yield n: 29
  in print_prime_numbes, n =  29
29
```

Here, because 25 is divisible, next number, 27, is being generated. I want to know what makes the calling to generate 27?

**[Edited]**

After yield 23, and go to next loop, the odd_numbers should be something like this:
filter(_not_divisible(23),filter(_not_divisible(19) ...filter(_not_divisible(7),filter(_not_divisible(5),filter(_not_divisible(5),filter(_not_divisible(3), _odd_generator())).

When running "yield n", the next number 25, is being generated and check the divisibility, and _not_divisible return False. Here, looks like the 'yield' will run next on _odd_generator() and check if the new number can be divided by 3,4,5,..23 until it gets a prime. But I want to know the mechanism here in details.

Comment: That's not a sieve - it's trial division.

Comment: you are right, it's not a sieve accurately. any comments regarding to my question are welcome.

Comment: It's not clear what confuses you about the 27. `_odd_number_generator` goes in steps of 2. 25+2=27, so after processing the 25, the next number pulled out of the generator is 27.

Comment: „I want to know what makes the calling to generate 27?“ The line ˋx += 2ˋ, where ˋxˋ previously was 25. Or are you asking specifically how ˋnextˋ works? In that case, I recommend looking at generators in isolation, without dozens of lines of code doing other things.

Comment: I reedited my question. please see the new lines.

Comment: „The mechanism here in detail“ can be anything from „the same as for 25“ to „next(_primes) calls next(odd_numbers) which yields x which is checked by a stack of _not_divisible“ to „the CPython runtime uses stackfull coroutines which *technobabble*“. Please clarify exactly what you need, ideally with a minimal use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For better understanding, we can look at `filter` as a generator as well:

```
def filter(condition, iterable):
    for value in iterable:      # 1. consume values from `iterable`
        if condition(value):    # 2. test `condition` for `value`
            yield value         # 3. yield any valid `value`
```

In other words, `odd_numbers = filter(_not_divisible(n), odd_numbers)` is a generator (`filter`) wrapping another generator (`_odd_number_generator`). For every prime number, a new `filter` is wrapped around the existing wrapped filters. Looking at one of the initial cases, we have this setup:

```
odd_numbers = filter(_not_divisible(n=7),  # <filter A>
    filter(_not_divisible(n=5),            # <filter B>
        filter(_not_divisible(n=3),        # <filter C>
            _odd_number_generator()        # <odd_numbers @ x=7>
))
```

Now, what happens if we call `next(odd_numbers)`?

- `<filter A>:1` fetches a `value` by calling `next(<filter B>)`

  - `<filter B>:1` fetches a `value` by calling `next(<filter C>)`

    - `<filter C>:1` fetches a `value` by calling `next(<odd_numbers @ x=7>)`

      - `<odd_numbers @ x=7>` increments `x+=2` to `x=9` and yields it
    - `<filter C>:2` tests `_not_divisible(n=3)(9)` and finds it **invalid**
    - `<filter C>:3` is **skipped** and the loop continues
    - `<filter C>:1` fetches a `value` by calling `next(<odd_numbers @ x=9>)`

      - `<odd_numbers @ x=9>` increments `x+=2` to `x=11` and yields it
    - `<filter C>:2` tests `_not_divisible(n=3)(11)` and finds it valid
    - `<filter C>:3` yields 11
  - `<filter B>:2` tests `_not_divisible(n=5)(11)` and finds it valid
  - `<filter B>:3` yields 11
- `<filter A>:2` tests `_not_divisible(n=7)(11)` and finds it valid
- `<filter A>:3` yields 11

The important part is that `_not_divisible(n=3)` does not let the value 9 pass. Instead, the loop in `<filter C>` fetches another value *without* yielding to `<filter B>` and `<filter A>`.

As more and more `filter(_not_divibible(n), ...)` layers are wrapped around `_odd_number_generator()`, there are additional layers which do the "skip `yield` and request new `value`". The general principle, that an intermediate generator can consume *several* values before yielding, remains the same.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation and thanks for the pseudo codes of filter(), this help me understanding too much.